# How to work with multiple time zones in .Net Micro Framework 4.2?

Tags: timezone, .net-micro-framework

I need to get the current time in 3 different time zones. There doesn't seem to be a way to get different time zone information in the .net micro framework v4.2. Does anyone know how I would do this?

Comment: That's just not possible.  It runs on very limited hardware, not the kind that boots a Windows operating system and has a database of timezones available.  Do review what kind of classes you have available on Micro to see if it is appropriate for your application.  Such a review will not take long, it is very, well, micro.

Comment: @HansPassant - I did a review of the micro framework libraries. Microsoft documentation says there is a class called "ExtendedTimeZone" that will allow you to set timezones, using a "TimeZoneId". That would work for me, but the problem is that class doesn't actually exist in the 4.2 code base. It is supposed to be in the Microsoft.SPOT.Native dll, but it isn't.

Comment: It appears that "ExtendedTimeZone" class was in previous version of the framework (like 4.1). My guess is Microsoft removed it to shrink the size, due to not having the time zone database files. However there is still a need for this, so this should probably be released in a seperate DLL, etc. It looks like I might have to roll my own here..